# Can't deploy to ebs getting aws.auth.client.error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can any one tell me why I am getting this issue when I run eb deploy or eb create name-dev

```
ERROR: aws.auth.client.error.ARCInstanceIdentityProfileNotFoundException: 
ERROR: Failed to launch environment
INFO: Deleting SNS topic for environment name-dev
```

Is what I am doing wrong the environment name? or is the access key which I had sent wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Jagdish.

Comment: this doesn't look like an access key issue. not sure what the error is though. if retrying doesn't help I suggest you'd contact Amazon support.

Comment: Thank you @Tal I resolved this issue by giving user full admin access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is happening because your IAM user doesn't have the necessary access for that command. I got the same error and was able to resolve it by giving the IAM user full admin access. Probably not what you want for production though.

Comment: Thank you @Caleb I did same by giving user full admin access

Answer (score 4):

The following AWS documentation link covers how to configure IAM Roles for Elastic Beanstalk:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.aeb.html

The default PowerUser profile provided by AWS denies all access to the IAM service, which results in this error.  The following IAM permissions are required for Elastic Beanstalk:

```
"iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
"iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
"iam:CreateRole",
"iam:PassRole",
"iam:ListInstanceProfiles"
```

The docs have full examples showing how to grant access to a broad set of AWS resources without granting full administrative access.

Comment: Thank you @copperlight I resolved by giving user full admin access.